# Drop down list on submodule in sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

Lets discuss with diagram. just have look on below image and understand the question what i am looking exact.

[image: screenshot]

We have Module List, in which sales, marketing, support, activities,collaboration & all this module is include
Then we have sub module list respected with module list like, in Sales we have Home, Account, Contact, Opportunities & Leads.
Now considered above images in which i have selected Sales as module & account as sub-module. Then we can see below that Recent View:none & Action: Create Account View Account Import account. 
So instead of this recent view & action can we put drop down list on mouse hover effect meaning when cursor is on account that time we can see drop down list of 
Create Account
View Account
Import Account.

Comment: For image just go here http://devendrakharde.blogspot.in/2012/11/drop-down-list-on-submodulelist-in.html

Answer (score 1):

There are alternate themes that do this already, such as...

http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/bluetheme/

Or, you could upgrade to Pro and the default theme there does this as well.

Comment: Thanks For the Reply, I have tried this SpecINFO_Blue theme but there is no Group tab i.e modulelist, submodulelist. There is directly Modulelist and on that drop down list. But i want ModuleList them SubModuleList & then Drop down list on it. Can we make this type of structure in SpecINFO_Blue theme, if this possible then it's also ok